# Best way to handle save file migrations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title suggests I'm trying to find the best way to handle save game files migrations and not blow up my whole codebase. From web development I know an up-down migration technique and while I see how it can be applied to unity, I have a hard time figuring out how to use it relatively easy.

My current idea is to:
Create an interface responsible for doing the said up-down migration, so it'd be some kind of a chain of responsibility, I'd then store each data class in it's respected namespace. Let's assume I have some BallData, it contains position and color, so it looks like this : 
`Ball Data { Vector3 Position; Color Color; }`
Then I decide that I want it to have a BorderColor, this is additive change, it's fine.
Next day game designer comes in and says "We don't have just a BorderColor anymore, it's a bad idea, we now have a top and bottom border colors" and some imaginary 100 players have already played this update with borderColor feature, I say "Sure" and wrap ball data into the new namespaces based on each change version, now I end up with

```
namespace BallDataV1 {
   BallData { Vector3 Position, Color Color; }
}

namespace BallDataV2 {
   BallData { Vector3 Position, Color Color, Color BorderColor; }
}

namespace BallDataV3 {
   BallData { Vector3 Position, Color Color, Color TopBorderColor; Color BottomBorderColor }
}
```

So each migration version knows about the old structure of things and can translate changes to a new structure. In this example the BallDataV2 to BallDataV3 knows exactly that BorderColor is not a thing anymore, we can put the BorderColor into the TopBorderColor tho. There're now a TopBorderColor and BottomBorderColor fields, it is handy to have namespace per data class version or even a simple class instance with the version suffix however I find it very hard and clunky to work with, especially since I have already about 15 different systems that want to be saved/loaded and would have data changed as game keeps constantly changing and evolving, this is going to end up with a very big amount of code and data, especially since my game is going to be released in an alpha and awaits a bunch of updates!

Thank you very much for any answers in advance, Let me know if something is not clear!

Comment: Maybe you could make.use of the [`FormerSerializedAs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serialization.FormerlySerializedAsAttribute.html) attribute and keep the date around just in case later you wanted to add it again?

Comment: Thanks for your input @derHugo unfortunately that's not what I need. I use FormerSerializedAs when I want to rename the field globally and leave the reference pointing at the same objects or having the same values in case it's a primitive, but this is more of an architecture question about the save data migrations from the old build to the new build without ruining user's experience and not shooting myself in the leg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the versioned data far away from my actual game code. If your data is really that volatile you may even opt to not create classes for it in the first place, but rather store the stuff in a dynamic serialized format. Then you can write a single Serializer to serialize the stuff to files and a bunch of different Deserializers to account for the versions. Lets go with your Ball structure for now and assume you have some GameState object which holds a list of balls.

```cs
class GameState {
   List<BallStructure> balls;
}

class BallStructure {
   Vector3 position;
   Color color;
}
```

Now you can use a serializer to serialize this.

```cs
public class Serializer {
    const string SerializationVersion = "1";
    public string SerializeToString(GameState gameState) {
        // some magic that turns the thing into a string, maybe a JSON
    }
}
```

Now your savegame file holds this:

```
{
   "_serializationVersion": "1"
   balls : [
      {
         "position" : "1,2,5",
         "color" : "#289328"
      },
      {
         "position" : "1,2,5",
         "color" : "#289328"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now you can write some deserializer that can read this back into a `GameState` object.

```cs
class Deserializer {
     public GameState Deserialize(string input) {
         // some json parsing magic and you get the game state back
     }
}
```

Now lets go with your example and you have meanwhile had 3 iterations, so your serializer would now look like this:

```cs
public class Serializer {
    const string SerializationVersion = "3";
    public string SerializeToString(GameState gameState) {
        // some magic that turns the thing into a string, maybe a JSON
    }
}
```

Nothing changes for your game code. It still works on a `GameState` object. The `Deserializer` now needs to account for some versions though:

```cs
class Deserializer {
     public GameState Deserialize(string input) {
        var jsonObject = JSONParser.Parse(input);
        var version = jsonObject.Get("_serializationVersion");
        if (version  == "1") {
            return DerserializeFromVersion1(jsonObject);
        }
        if (version  == "2") {
            return DerserializeFromVersion2(jsonObject);
        }
        if (version  == "3") {
            return DerserializeFromVersion3(jsonObject);
        }
     }

     private GameState DeserializeFromVersion1(JSONObject jsonObject) {
     }
     private GameState DeserializeFromVersion2(JSONObject jsonObject) {
     }
     private GameState DeserializeFromVersion3(JSONObject jsonObject) {
     }
}
```

Again, the details are hidden inside the deserializer. Both your game code and the serializer use always the latest and greatest version. The deserializer handles migrating loaded games into this latest version. Of course if you have more than just this simple example, you will probably amp this up a bit (e.g. have one deserializer per version and aggregate these in the deserializer class that your game code works with), e.g.

```cs
class Deserializer {
    private List<Deserializer> supportedDeserializers = new List<..>(); // get some instances here e.g. with dependency injection

     public GameState Deserialize(string input) {
        var jsonObject = // ... same code as above
        var version = // ... same code as above;
        for(var deserializer in supportedDeserializers) {
            if (deserializer.SupportsVersion(version)) {
                return deserializer.Deserialize(jsonObject);
            }
        }

     }
}

interface IDeserializer {
    bool CanDeserializeVersion(string version);
    GameState Deserialize(JsonObject object);
}

class V1Deserializer : IDeserializer {
   // ...
}

class V2Deserializer : IDeserializer {
   // ...
}

class V3Deserializer : IDeserializer {
   // ...
}
```

This way your game code can just call the main deserializer and be happy and you don't need to juggle around all kinds of versions of your domain objects.

Of course there may always be situation when a migration is simply not possible, e.g if you decide to remove the balls from your game altogether and replace them with spaceships. Also while being in the pre-release stages it might be a good idea to tell your testers that savegames of the alpha and beta version may not be compatible with the final version or at least announce breaking changes well ahead of time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, this is very helpful. Yes I'll have to deprecate the data at some point, since this is a single player game - it's probably okay to provide users a cheat so they can get back to the progress they had before the data lose but I think I can run the idea through the community first. Your approach looks quite similar to mine except you use a dynamic data here. I have had some thoughts about utilizing xml-like structure to handle some of the migrations so each version has instructions what to do without any code but not sure how flexible would it be!